# I nead a python code that can operate changes on data imbricated between a specific character

Tags: python

for example, I have csv data structure like this:

| data |
| --- |
| new |
| 5,9,7 |
| 3,8,1 |
| 2,9,6 |
| new |
| 5,9,3 |
| 8,4,9 |
| new |
| 8,3,9 |
| 5,4,7 |
| 1,6,7 |
| 1,2,8 |

the output I expect is this

| data |
| --- |
| new |
| 5,9,7 |
| 2,9,6 |
| new |
| 5,9,3 |
| 8,4,9 |
| new |
| 8,3,9 |
| 1,2,8 |

Note that only the first and the last row of the data between every occurrence of the string "new" are retained.

I tried to do that by splitting the data to separate files every occurrence of "new" and the make changes, but that take me a lot of time since i have large amount of data

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried, why did it fail? We expect users to provide some code that does not work and a specific question regarding this code/algorithm. Which libraries do you use - pandas or just base Python?

Comment: Where does the output go?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the elements between your `"new"` breaks by storing them in a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects) and removing just the head and tail when you reach the next break in your data. Also one thing to note is that I have included logic to handle the situation where there is only *one* element in between breaks as opposed to *two or more*. I wasn't sure what your actual data looks like.

```
import csv
from collections import deque
from io import StringIO

s = """data
new
5,9,7
3,8,1
2,9,6
new
5,9,3
8,4,9
new
8,3,9
5,4,7
1,6,7
1,2,8
"""

data = StringIO(s)
dq = deque()
to_keep = []
reader = csv.reader(data)
to_keep.append(next(reader))  # append the header

for row in reader:
    if row[0] == "new":
        if len(dq) == 1:  # handle the case of 1 element between breaks
            to_keep.append(dq.pop())
        elif len(dq) > 1:
            vals = [dq.popleft(), dq.pop()]
            to_keep.extend(vals)
            dq.clear()
        to_keep.append(row)
    else:
        dq.append(row)

# handle the final iteration after the last break
vals = [dq.popleft(), dq.pop()]
to_keep.extend(vals)

print(to_keep)
[['data'],
 ['new'],
 ['5', '9', '7'],
 ['2', '9', '6'],
 ['new'],
 ['5', '9', '3'],
 ['8', '4', '9'],
 ['new'],
 ['8', '3', '9'],
 ['1', '2', '8']]
```

---

Below is how the code looks like when reading and writing to a file in tandem.

```
dq = deque()

with open("outfile.csv", "w") as fout, open("infile.csv", "r") as fin:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer.writerow(next(reader))

    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == "new":
            if len(dq) == 1:  # handle the case of 1 element between breaks
                writer.writerow(dq.pop())
            elif len(dq) > 1:
                vals = [dq.popleft(), dq.pop()]
                writer.writerows(vals)
                dq.clear()
            writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            dq.append(row)

    # handle the final iteration after the last break
    vals = [dq.popleft(), dq.pop()]
    writer.writerows(vals)
```